# Mulesoft- Sql select connector query issue

Tags: mule4

I see the below error while connect and pull the records from the database through the Mule Database connector with an Oracle database. Can someone look at it and let me know what's wrong with this query.

Error:

```
"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended\n"
type: DB:BAD_SQL_SYNTAX
```

Query:

```
SELECT A.sample_central_id,A.req_ndc_prod_id,B.lot_num,A.req_product_desc,A.req_hcp_fst_name,A.req_hcp_last_name,A.req_prof_desig,A.az_hcp_id,A.req_addr_line_1,A.req_addr_line_2,A.req_city,A.req_state_cd,A.req_zipcode,A.ffevnt_shipped_qty,A.ffevnt_ship_dt FROM scrf.ship_prod_hist_vw A,scrfval.ship_dtl B WHERE  Trunc(A.req_sample_requested_dt)>= Trunc(SYSDATE - 30)AND Trunc(A.req_sample_requested_dt)<= Trunc(SYSDATE + 10)AND Trunc(A.ffevnt_ship_dt)>= Trunc(SYSDATE - 8)AND Trunc(A.ffevnt_ship_dt)<Trunc(SYSDATE - 1)AND Upper(A.lkp_brand_desc) LIKE '%LYNPARZA%' AND A.sample_central_id = B.sc_req_id AND A.ffevnt_ff_vendor_id = B.shipment_id AND A.req_ndc_prod_id = B.ndc_prod_id AND A.ffevnt_shipped_qty<>0 ORDER  BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semicolon (';') at the end.